# How to change tapped listview item image xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having the list of images I'm using the converter to change the image. When I tapped the images all the images are changed I need to change the tapped image only in MVVM. somebody please guide.

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? "progressicon.png" : "cloud_download.png";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

[Download icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kam5E.png)    [icon change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZZ2A.png)

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding DateTime,Converter={StaticResource timestampconverter }}" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="300" />
    <Grid>
        <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                HeightRequest="40"  
                                IsVisible="{Binding ToDownload}" 
                                Source="{Binding BindingContext.DownloadIcon, Converter={StaticResource downloadiconconverter},Source={x:Reference listview}}"
                                WidthRequest="35" Command ="{Binding BindingContext.Download, Source={x:Reference listview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
        <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                HeightRequest="40" 
                                IsVisible="{Binding ToUpload}"    
                                Source="{Binding BindingContext.UploadIcon, Converter={StaticResource uploadiconconverter},Source={x:Reference listview}}"
                                WidthRequest="35"  Command ="{Binding BindingContext.Upload, Source={x:Reference listview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: post your converter code as well, is your converter converts Bool value to Image source

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

**Downloadiconconverter:**

```
public class Downloadiconconverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? "progressicon.png":"cloud_download.png";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return false; // not needed
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding DateTime,Converter={StaticResource timestampconverter }}" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="300" />
    <Grid>
        <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                HeightRequest="40"  
                                IsVisible="{Binding ToDownload}" 
                                Source="{Binding IsDownloading, Converter={StaticResource downloadiconconverter},Source={x:Reference listview}}"
                                WidthRequest="35" Command ="{Binding BindingContext.Download, Source={x:Reference listview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
        <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                HeightRequest="40" 
                                IsVisible="{Binding ToUpload}"    
                                Source="{Binding IsUploading, Converter={StaticResource uploadiconconverter},Source={x:Reference listview}}"
                                WidthRequest="35"  Command ="{Binding BindingContext.Upload, Source={x:Reference listview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

**Model Class:**

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(new { DateTime = "15/02/2019", ToDownload = true, IsDownloading=false });
```

**View Model code:**

```
private bool? isDownloading;

public bool? IsDownloading
 {
    get { return isDownloading; }
    set
    {
       isDownloading = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("IsDownloading");
    }
 }
```

Similarly you can do for uploading scenario case.